# Write into text file

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have two equations generated from Android accelerometer sensor. The first equation I called **TotalAccelerate** that represents **valueAfterMovingAverage** and second equation I called **FrontalSpeed**. The goal is to write both values - separated by a space -  at a time into my text file. Here is the code I found and it is been writing only the first quation value. 
How can write the second equation value along with the first value? 
The result has to be something like this:

```
10    7
8     9
7.5   6
 .    .
 .    .
```

here is my code I try:

```
double TotalAccelerate;
double FrontalSpeed;
ArrayList<Double> listPeaks;
ArrayList<Double>listOfFrontal;


@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listPeaks = new ArrayList<Double>();
    listOfFrontal = new ArrayList<Double>();
}//End OnCreate()

 @Override
public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    // The light sensor returns a single value.
    // Many sensors return 3 values, one for each axis.
    if (isListening) {
        double xx = event.values[0];
        double yy = event.values[1];
        double zz = event.values[2];
        TotalAccelerate = Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xx, 2)
                + Math.pow(yy, 2)
                + Math.pow(zz, 2)));
        Log.i(DEBUG, "Accelerometer = " + TotalAccelerate);


        FrontalSpeed =  Math.round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xx, 2)
                + Math.pow(zz, 2))); //Second equation


          Log.i(DEBUG, "list values " + listPeaks);

        MovingAverage ma = new MovingAverage(2);
        ma.newNum(TotalAccelerate);
        valueAfterMovingAverage= (float) ma.getAvg();
        sensorText.setText(String.valueOf(valueAfterMovingAverage));
        Log.i(DEBUG, "Moving avg:  " + valueAfterMovingAverage);
        listPeaks.add((double) valueAfterMovingAverage);
        listOfFrontal.add(FrontalSpeed); //I think this is wrong, I should add the values to the same list above 
and concatenate with space. 
     }

}

 OnStore = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.onStore);
    OnStore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (OnStore.isChecked()) {
                //
                // set listening flag to true
                //
                isListening = true;


            } else if (!OnStore.isChecked()) { //
                // set listening flag to false
                //
                isListening = false;

                try {
                    for (double valueAfterMovingAverage : listPeaks) {
                        String space = "\n";
                        byte[] convert = space.getBytes();
                        fileOutputStream.write(convert);
                        String finalData;
                        String speedSignal = String.valueOf(FrontalSpeed);

                        finalData = String.valueOf(valueAfterMovingAverage);

                        fileOutputStream.write(Integer.parseInt(finalData.getBytes()+" " + speedSignal)); //my attempt. 
                           Log.i(DEBUG, "ans: " + finalData);
                       // fileOutputStream.write(Integer.parseInt(speedSignal));
                      }
                    fileOutputStream.flush();
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message saving", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Stopped.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: int value1=100: int value2=1234; String line = value1 + " " + value2 +"\n"; out.write(line.getBytes());

Comment: Your method works, but I have the second column, has all same values. What is the issue?

Comment: Well that is for you to find out. Why sould that be difficult?

Comment: I think it is because of the loop, It takes the values of my first equation but not the second one. But I don't know how to fix it. I will try anyway. But thanks a lot.

Comment: Excuse me, could you give me a hit? I couldn't solve it yet

Comment: Sorry. I do not understand your code.